# Apply sliding window operation without aggregation in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Can we apply Kafka window operations without aggregation something like "I want all data (not the counts) that came in last 10 minutes"? What I see is that most of the example uses aggregation with window sliding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KafkaConsumer#offsetsForTimes` method to get the offsets "10 minutes ago" in a map of partitions to offsets.

Using that information, loop over the map and `seek` your consumer to those partition offsets.

Then start polling until the record timestamps are outside your requested time window.

Otherwise, you can try using Kafka Steams reduce function to aggregate your data into a collection to process as a whole rather than only accumulate some other way (this may require a custom serde)