# Kafka Streams DSL save to state store without aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to use Kafka Streams DSL to consume and save the messages in local state store without performing any aggregation?
What I am trying to do is to read and group all incoming messages in windows (say 5 minutes window size, and 5 hours retention) without updating/aggregating the messages.
Then later I can use the interactive queries to retrieve historical messages, say last 1 hour.
From what I have seen, the only way to save the messages in state store is through aggregation which is not what I want.

Comment: Seems to be related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70255933/apply-sliding-window-operation-without-aggregation-in-kafka

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks. Yes, it is the same question. But the response suggests to use Consumer API is not what I want. I am looking Kafka Streams Interactive Queries to read the data from state store. Instead of using DSL, I just found the Processor API might be what I need. But I am getting an error when read the message from state store, it said "KafkaStreams is not running." `Topology builder = new Topology(); builder.addSource("Source", "source-topic") .addProcessor("Process", () -> new WordCountProcessor(), "Source") .addStateStore(countStoreBuilder, "Process") `

Comment: I also suggested you can use `reduce()` function to aggregate to a collection. Regarding your error, you only defined the topology. Are you building the topology and calling `KafkaStreams#start` method?

Comment: Yes, I did call KafkaStreams#start.  I found out the error "KafkaStreams is not running." was because I did not have  addSink() process.  Once I added, the error went away.   But now when I publish say 10 messages, and when I use interactive query to read from state store, it only returns the last message.  Was it doing the Update instead of Insert when persisting to local state store?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, in regard to use reduce() to aggregate to a collection, would you mind providing an example. I would prefer to use DSL API if possible. Again what I am looking to achieve is, when I publish 10 messages, I want to be able to get exactly 10 original messages out of state store.  Will reduce() be aggregating to one single message?  I am new to kafka streams. Thanks!

Comment: So, I guess my question is what do you define as "aggregate"? Sums and counts are not the only option. Here is an example that aggregates a stream of strings and outputs a single space-separated string - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/ReduceTest.java#L114 ... Something similar can be done with `v1.addAll(v2)`, if both elements are already lists. Then producing that to a downstream topic will output a single list-value message

Comment: Regarding what I wrote about Serdes in the linked post, checkout this repo, and see how this class is used for Interactive Queries - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java#L469

Comment: As I said I do not want ANY computation, count, concatenation (v1+v2),...etc on the message.  I want the Kafka Streams reads in 10 messages and stores 10 messages in their original form in local state store.  That's what I meant in this thread title "without aggregation".  Later I want to use interactive query to read these 10 messages from state store.

Comment: The store itself is not bounded by time, therefore you are limited by key-lookup. To get "10 elements" for one key of the store, it is required to be aggregated into a collection, such as the `TopFiveSongs` class I linked to. Otherwise, the only other option is to iterate all keys of the store, which can be more/less than 10

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.